# Como trabalhar com cabeçalho de autenticação JWT no AdonisJS?

Tags: jwt, http-headers, adonisjs

Indo direto ao ponto, eu quero saber como trabalhar de forma correta com JWT no AdonisJS (estou aprendendo a usar o framework e nunca havia antes trabalhado com JWT). O meu problema agora é que eu não quero ficar pegando o Bearer Token gerado lá no meu Postman e setar ele no cabeçalho para poder ter acesso às minhas rotas que precisam de autenticação. Então, eu preciso primeiro entender como eu passo o token para o cabeçalho diretamente para testar no browser. Estou fazendo assim hoje, mas não sei se é o correto:

```js
"use strict";

class SessionController {
  async authenticate({ request, auth, response }) {
    const { email, password } = request.all();

    const token = await auth.attempt(email, password);

    response.response.setHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${token.token}`);
  }
}

module.exports = SessionController;
```

No exemplo acima eu já tenho o usuário registrado no banco de dados, apenas gero para ele o token. Eu quero que esse token fique persistido no browser, não sei se estou sendo claro quanto a isso, a ideia é que a partir da resposta desta função acima, ele já possa acessar as rotas que necessitam de autenticação.

abaixo o controller de inserção de usuário:

```js
"use strict";

const User = use("App/Models/User");

class UserController {
  async register({ request }) {
    const data = request.only(["username", "password", "email"]);

    const user = await User.create(data);

    return user;
  }
}
module.exports = UserController;
```

agora, por fim, as minhas rotas:

```js
"use strict";

/** @type {typeof import('@adonisjs/framework/src/Route/Manager')} */
const Route = use("Route");

Route.post("/register", "UserController.register");
Route.post("/authenticate", "SessionController.authenticate");
Route.post("/test", "WorkerController.store").middleware(["auth"]);
```

Como pode-se ver, eu tenho uma rota TEST que chama o a função store da classe Worker, vou mostrá-la, mas já digo que esta rota é basicamente para ver se a autenticação está passando... ou seja, se depois de eu autenticar lá na minha rota /authenticate, eu já consigo acessa a /test pelo browser (daí a necessidade de deixar o cabeçalho de autorização persistido no navegador)

```js
"use strict";

class WorkerController {
  async store({ request, response, auth }) {
    console.log(auth.user.email);
  }
}

module.exports = WorkerController;
```

Comment: O middleware de autenticação é claro no que faz: só vai deixar você acessar as rotas se você tiver o _header_ de autorização com um token válido. Você quer mudar esse comportamento?

Comment: Boa noite Luiz, no browser, após eu fazer um post na rota de autenticação, ele me retorna o cabeçalho com authorization: bearer + token, só que se eu tentar já bater um /test na url, ele retorna 401 unauthorized

Comment: esse não seria já o meu token válido?

Comment: Ele retorna 401 por que você provavelmente não definiu o cabeçalho `Authorization: Bearer <token>` na sua **requisição ao servidor**. Leia mais sobre isso na [documentação](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication#_jwt). Você sempre deverá definir esse cabeçalho na sua requisição. Usando ferramentas como o Postman, por exemplo, você tem uma seção de "cabeçalhos" para inserir esse dado.

Comment: A documentação somente diz que se deve fazer isto, não mostra como, talvez esse seja o problema. Você pode me mostrar como eu faria isto?! Eu não quero ficar setando isto no Postman, disse na introdução da pergunta. Eu gostaria de entender como fazer isso diretamente pelo browser.

Comment: "O meu problema agora é que eu não quero ficar pegando o Bearer Token gerado lá no meu Postman e setar ele no cabeçalho para poder ter acesso às minhas rotas que precisam de autenticação. Então, eu preciso primeiro entender como eu passo o token para o cabeçalho diretamente para testar no browser."

Comment: Se você estiver utilizando o Postman, sempre terá que fazer isso manualmente. Desconheço uma forma de automatizar esse processo.

Comment: A ideia é apenas fazer um sistema de login? No caso, uma API para ser consumida em um frontend?

Comment: Sim, victor... estou fazendo a api para consumir em react js/ react native. Concorda comigo que eu não tenho como ficar setando autorização em cabeçalho manualmente na hora de consumir? sabe como me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

O `Bearer Authentication` (significa autenticação ao Portador):

> A autenticação do portador (também chamada de autenticação por `token`) é um esquema de autenticação `HTTP` que envolve `tokens` de segurança chamados `tokens` do portador. O nome “autenticação do portador” pode ser entendido como “dar acesso ao portador desse `token`”. O `token` portador é uma string críptica, geralmente gerada pelo servidor em resposta a uma solicitação de login. O cliente deve enviar este `token` no cabeçalho `Authorization` ao fazer solicitações para recursos protegidos.

Logo, esclarecido sobre o `Bearer` e levando em consideração que você saiba o funcionamento do `JWT`, vamos as suas perguntas:

> "O meu problema agora é que eu não quero ficar pegando o Bearer Token gerado lá no meu Postman e setar ele no cabeçalho para poder ter acesso às minhas rotas que precisam de autenticação."

**R:** A Tecnologia do `JWT` e `Bearer Authentication` é bem clara quanto a isto. Resumidamente é necessário que você possua o `Token` de autenticação que é recebido do `JWT`, e ainda mais necessário que você passe o mesmo no `header` (cabeçalho) `Authorization` com o prefixo `Bearer`, deste modo: `Authorization: Bearer <token>`.

Então com isto, é de extrema importância você conter o `token` de autenticação `JWT` e passar o mesmo no `header` (cabeçalho) para poder acessar as suas rotas entre outros recursos que necessitam do mesmo.

> Então, eu preciso primeiro entender como eu passo o `token` para o cabeçalho diretamente para testar no browser.

**R:** Geralmente ocorre da seguinte forma, utilizando um exemplo simples de login. Possuindo as seguintes páginas:

- Login
- Autenticação
- Index

Ao adentrar na página "login" o usuário irá fazer uma requisição para o servidor com os seus dados (username, password, etc), porém esta requisição é feita na página "autenticação". Logo em seguida caso aqueles dados sejam verdadeiros (ai depende da sua lógica), será encaminhado como resposta o `token` do usuário (lembrando que irá vir da página "autenticação"), assim que você receber o `token`, você deve encaminhar uma requisição com ele no cabeçalho para a página "index".

Como eu disse, tudo depende da sua lógica e de como está no seu backend, por exemplo.. Acima eu dei um exemplo de recebendo o `token` do backend, manipulando ele no frontend em conjunto com o seu backend, porém você poderia manipular o mesmo direto do seu backend.

Comment: Boa noite, Thiago! Eu consigo gerar o meu token normalmente, o adonisjs me ajuda bastante nisso. O meu problema é realmente o código para passar o token para o cabeçalho, qual função usar no Adonis, isso não fica claro na documentação. Tentei Response.Headers() e nada... response.response.header(), de jeito algum consigo passar o bendito para o cabeçalho...

Answer (score 0):

Se por acaso alguém tiver esta mesma dúvida que eu, abaixo segue o código que usei para setar o Authorization + token no cabeçalho, e depois capturar os dados do usuário portador do token:

**setando o header:**

```js
"use strict";

class SessionController {
  async authenticate({ request, auth, response }) {
    try {
      const { email, password } = request.all();
      const token = await auth.attempt(email, password);

      if (token) {
        return response.response.setHeader(
          "Authorization",
          `Bearer ${token.token}`
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("email ou senha inválidos");
    }
  }
}

module.exports = SessionController;
```

**pegando dos dados (escrevendo email no console e retornando id)**

```js
"use strict";

class WorkerController {
  async store({ request, response, auth }) {
    console.log(auth.user.email);

    const id = auth.user.id;

    return id;
  }
}

module.exports = WorkerController;
```